# How do I install Latin Modern Math with basictex?

Tags: fonts

I've installed the `basictex` package in OSX and it mentions that it includes the "Latin Modern" fonts.

> It contains AMSTeX, the **Latin Modern Fonts**, the TeX Live Manager to add and update packages from TeX Live, and the new SyncTeX.

I'm not sure why I'm still getting this error though:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "latinmodern-math.otf" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

I'm trying to convert [Awesome-CV](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) via `xelatex examples/resume.tex`.

Comment: Welcome! Life will be much easier if you just install MacTeX. You are very likely to need further packages, classes, fonts, scripts....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`lm-math` is a separate TeX Live package. You can install it with the Max OS X application "TeX Live Utility", which is a wrapper around the command-line `tlmgr` programme:

[image]

You have to right-click and select "install selected packages"  when lm-math selected.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed with installing this font

```
tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```