# Who can write a package to call for upright Greek lowercase letters compatible with the computer modern italic ones?

Tags: math-mode, greek

**Update**

Now some volunteer contacts me and the project begins. Thanks go to all the readers.

---

---

Sometimes we need to call for upright Greek lowercase letters compatible with the computer modern italic ones in shapes. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145926/140814) is a solution for which XeLaTeX couldn't be used. And as follows @David Carlisle also gives a solution involving the `unicode-math` package which may be clashed with some other packages, for example, the `mathspec` package. So it's necessary to create a *single and smart* package to invoke computer modern upright greek lowercase letters as mathematical symbols.

Now I've created the regular and bold OTF font files for them, then who can write a package maybe called `cmupgreek` (there is already a [`upgreek`](https://ctan.org/pkg/upgreek) package for upright Greek letters from the Euler or Adobe Symbol fonts)?

The following is the screen shots for shapes of them.

[image]

[image]

The commands for them are as follows, and we could get the bold ones if we use `\mathbf{}`, `\boldmath` and so on.

```
Command Unicode
\upalpha 03B1
\upbeta 03B2
\upgamma 03B3
\updelta 03B4
\upepsilon 03B5
\upzeta 03B6
\upeta 03B7
\uptheta 03B8
\upiota 03B9
\upkappa 03BA
\uplambda 03BB
\upmu 03BC
\upnu 03BD
\upxi 03BE
\upomicron 03BF
\uppi 03C0
\uprho 03C1
\upsigma 03C3
\uptao 03C4
\upupsilon 03C5
\upphi 03C6
\upchi 03C7
\uppsi 03C8
\upomega 03C9
\upvartheta 03D1
\upvarphi 03D5
\upvarpi 03D6
\upvarsigma 03D8
\upvarkappa 03F0
\upvarrho 03F1
\upvarepsilon 03F5
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but what does this provide that is not in latin modern math and/or computer modern book, for example? Are the glyphs different? How?

Comment: @mickep These up Greek lowercase letters are not in LaTeX, but sometimes we need them.

Comment: Why not using, for example, the options given in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145926/201628)?

Comment: @Vincent 1. XeLaTeX could not be used; 2. the slant angles are different that it's not convenient to do that while I have adjusted them in the font files uniformly.

Comment: And `\mupalpha` and so on (using `unicode-math`) is not what you want? I assume you use luatex/xetex.

Comment: @mickep But we may need up and italic ones at the same time while if we use unicode-math to get the up ones in this way, we couldn't get the italic ones.

Comment: I do not understand. Try `\alpha\mupalpha\mbfalpha` for example.

Comment: @mickep I tried: 1. using the french or upright style in unicode-math (`\usepackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}` or `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}`), they are all up ones; 2. using only unicode-math (`\usepackage{unicode-math}`), they are all italic ones. And sometimes we may invoke packages clashed with unicode-math, for example, the `mathspec` package. So we need a simple package compatible with the other packages.

Comment: But then you have `\mitalpha`, don't you?

Comment: with any unicode math font lowercase greek is available in upright, bold upright, italic, bold italic,  bold sans serif (not normal weight sans serif), slanted bold sans serif, in the _same_ font, are you sure you need additional fonts? see https://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007doc/Overview.html#alphabets

Comment: The current package clashing situation is a bit complicated, but I don't think your proposal is a good idea either. The glyphs are already available in Latin Modern Math font files, duplicating to something-else would make the situation *more complicated*.

Comment: What engine do you intend to support? // Side note, this question appears to be similar to [xetex - Is there a way to use unicode-math in a limited fashion? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41454/is-there-a-way-to-use-unicode-math-in-a-limited-fashion)

Comment: @user202729 It may be more convenient in many cases, by creating a single and smart package which is compatible with many other packages.

Comment: Needless to say it's impossible for any package to be compatible with every other packages (new packages can be created), which "other packages" are you thinking about? mathspec?

Comment: @user202729 Your are right, and this shows that it's necessary to create a new package for some particular uses.

Comment: I think mathspec can already load otf font? So simply load the necessary characters from Latin modern font and use them? (although I don't know yet how to actually do that)

Comment: @user202729 You are right. But it doesn't give commands to invoke upright Greek lowercase letters.

Comment: Good point. Although any solution that answers the "unicode-math in limited fashion" question above would also answer this one. Maybe `unicode-math-table` can be used on this point (it has list of command → character mapping).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Any Unicode Math font includes Greek in upright, italic, bold upright, bold italic, bold sans serif and slanted bold sans serif.  `unicode-math` makes these available using `\sym...` commands, or you can simply type the characters directly:
`αβγ` (which also works in other contexts such as web pages).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$
\symup{\alpha}\symup{\beta}\symup{\gamma}
\symbfup{\alpha}\symbfup{\beta}\symbfup{\gamma}
\symit{\alpha}\symit{\beta}\symit{\gamma}
\symbfit{\alpha}\symbfit{\beta}\symbfit{\gamma}
\symbfsf{\alpha}\symbfsf{\beta}\symbfsf{\gamma}
\symbfsfit{\alpha}\symbfsfit{\beta}\symbfsfit{\gamma}
$

$αβγ$

\end{document}
```

this shows the Latin Modern font, so in the style of Computer Modern, but the same input works with any font. Adding `\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}` produces

[image]

---

As requested, an example not using `unicode-math` and showing how you can use *any* font with Unicode Mathematical Greek with no special package support needed. (I loaded the fonts by font name, you may need to use the file name if you have not configured fontconfig).

The example loads (but does not use) `mathspec` so you need xelatex here (otherwise the example would also work in lualatex)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathspec}% not needed here but just to show it is compatible
\usepackage{fontspec}

% _Any_ Font with Mathmatical Greek in Unicode positions will work here
% I am using some standard ones but you could use your new font

\newfontfamily\lmfont{Latin Modern Math}[NFSSFamily=lmmath]
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathlm{TU}{lmmath}{m}{n}

\newfontfamily\ncmfont{NewComputerModernMath}[NFSSFamily=ncmmath]
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathncm{TU}{ncmmath}{m}{n}

\newfontfamily\stxfont{STIX Two Math}[NFSSFamily=stix2math]
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathstix{TU}{stix2math}{m}{n}


\begin{document}

LM

$\mathlm{αβγ}$

NCM

$\mathncm{αβγ}$

Stix2

$\mathstix{αβγ}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: But sometimes some package is clashed with the `unicode-math` package, for example, the `mathespec` package. So it's necessary to create a single and smart package to invoke computer modern up greek lowercase letters as mathematical symbols, f.

Comment: @M.Logic No sorry you are mistaken. `Latin Modern Math` and `NewComputerModernMath` are both fonts in Computer modern style, with upper/lowercase Greek in upright,italic, bold upright and bold italic, you don't need any package at all (or even math mode) Just load the font with fontspec (or a primitive `\font` command and use the standard Unicode characters for Mathematical Greek: αβγ . As shown in this comment, you don't need to change fonts for the different styles. If you are using a package incompatible with loading a font, I am not sure what answer to give

Comment: But sometimes we indeed invoke packages such as `mathspec` which may be clashed with `unicode-math`. Anyway, thanks very much.

Comment: Looking around a bit there's [mathspec - How to use .otf font file as math font in XeLaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635542/how-to-use-otf-font-file-as-math-font-in-xelatex) but (annoyingly) there's no real solution there.

Comment: as I say you don't need to use unicode-math you could load the font with mathspec, or fontspec,  I'll add an example... @M.Logic

Comment: But I've already invoked some other otf  fonts on my PC by `mathspec`. What now I need are some upright greek lowercase letters as mathematical symbols, and the smart package to be created serves it.

Comment: @M.Logic I added an example using `mathspec` You do not need a package.

Comment: @user202729 example added

Comment: @M.Logic no you are using xelatex so unlike classic tex (16 alphabets of 256 characters) You have 256 alphabets of thousands of characters. You will not run out of math alphabets. You can of course take the two lines of code shown above, changd to set for your font, and save it as a package `.sty` file but that is all you need.

Comment: It's indeed a solution. While unfortunately many people don't install latin modern on their pcs, including me (I compiled the example and found it) ^-^... Anyway, thanks very much.

Comment: You are right that there are many symbols, but I always select some particular ones to satisfy my personal taste. For example, in fact I don't like very much the computer modern lowercase italic geek letters (none existed is my taste since there always some ugly one to me in the fonts)  which matches not very well with the old style fonts used now by me, and so I may design a new font for italic greek letters ...

Comment: @M.Logic certainly you can set up your own fonts, but the question asks about a package to load a font with Greek and the answer is that the package just needs the two lines shown, adapted to use whatever font name you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, latin modern is not installed on my mac since it says "./newexample.tex:10: Package fontspec Error: The font "Latin Modern Math" cannot be found."

Comment: @M.Logic I don't understand that last comment. Let's say your font is named `abc.otf` , you can use the code above replacing "Latin Modern Math" with "abc" and it will work (probably). Alternatively if you're okay with Latin Modern Math just somehow fix your TeX installation (Latin Modern Math should be installed by default). What's the problem?

Comment: @user202729 I don't know why it produces such problems since the MacTex installed on my Macbook is the newest and complete.

Comment: @M.Logic Probably https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285850/how-do-i-install-latin-modern-math-with-basictex, but if you want to use your own otf file then no need to do that. Either way it's getting unrelated to this answer